# Show that there are infinitely many $k$-consecutive positive integers s.t. Möbius function takes the same value.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, mobius-inversion, mobius-function

That is to say $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\mu \left ( n+1 \right )=\mu \left ( n+2 \right )=\cdots=\mu \left ( n+k \right )$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

I saw this problem in a number theory textbook and it appears in the exercises for the section talking about the Möbius inversion formula. I cannot come up with an effective idea to tackle it.

This is not a homework problem.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Try making all $k$ of them equal to $0$ by forcing each number to have a repeated prime factor. Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_k$ be any distinct prime numbers.

Then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the system of congruences
$$\begin{align}
  n + 1 & \equiv 0 \mod p_1^2 \\
  n + 2 & \equiv 0 \mod p_2^2 \\
  n + 3 & \equiv 0 \mod p_3^2 \\
  \vdots \\
  n + k & \equiv 0 \mod p_k^2
\end{align}$$

has infinitely many solutions $n$. For any such solution $n$, we have that
$n + m$ is divisible by $p_m^2$ for $m=1,2,3,\cdots,k$, and so we have that $\mu(n+m)=0$ for $m=1,2,3\cdots,k$

We see that there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that
$$ \mu(n+1)=\mu(n+2)=\mu(n+3)=\cdots=\mu(n+k)=0$$

---

**edit**

In fact, if $k \geq 4$ and for some $n$ we have that
$$ \mu(n+1)=\mu(n+2)=\mu(n+3)=\cdots=\mu(n+k)$$
then it must in fact be the case that
$$ \mu(n+1)=\mu(n+2)=\mu(n+3)=\cdots=\mu(n+k)=0$$

This is because amongst the set of numbers
$$\lbrace n+1, n+2, n+3, n+4\rbrace$$
there will be a multiple of $4$. The Möbius function evaluated at this multiple of $4$ will be $0$.

Comment: I see. Great idea to apply CRT here. Thanks!