# Prove $\prod_p{(1-\frac{3}{p^2})}>\frac{1}{8}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove $$\prod_p{\left(1-\frac{3}{p^2}\right)}>\frac{1}{8},$$

where $p$ through out all  prime numbers.

It' s equivalent to prove that $$ \sum_ {n = 1}^\infty \frac {3^{\Omega(n)}} {n^2} < 8,$$
where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factor of n. For example, $\Omega(p^a)=a$.

The product is $\approx0.125487$ when $p＜100000$.

Comment: What is the background ?What have you tried ? It could be helpful for someone else...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality

Comment: [Evaluating $\prod_p (1±4/p^2)$ in Closed Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135965/evaluating-prod-p1-pm4-p2-in-closed-form?noredirect=1) might be useful. Found using Approach0.

Comment: Where does this question come from? I've found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888561/m%c3%b6bius-function-equation?noredirect=1) which suggests that this could be an open problem.

Comment: @ErikSatie Someone asked me that is there infinitely many positive integers n such that n-1,n,n+1 are all squarefree numbers, I found it's related to this product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By taking the small primes away, it is enough to show that $\prod_{p \geq 7}{\left(1-\frac{3}{p^2}\right)} > \frac{75}{88}$.

If $p\geq 7$, $(1-3/p^2) \geq (1-1/p^2)^4$. Therefore, it is enough to show that $\prod_{p \geq 7}{\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}} < \left(\frac{88}{75}\right)^{1/4}$.

But expanding the product, we find that it is at most $1+\sum_{n \geq 49}{n^{-2}} \leq 1+1/48$. What remains to be shown is that $(1+1/48)^4 < 88/75$ and that is easy to check.