# Problem on largest prime divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a positive integer $n$, let $p(n)$ the largest prime divisor of $n$. Show that there exist infinitely many positive integers m such that $p(m − 1) < p(m) < p(m + 1)$.

Let $q$ be odd prime and $a<b$.
$q^{2^b} - 1 =(q-1)(q+1)(q^2+1)...(q^{2^{b-1}}+1)$
$q^{2^{a}}+1 $ is a divisor of $ q^{2^{b}}-1  $

I don't know how to get the required inequality.

Comment: How is the second paragraph related to the first?

Comment: I'm intending to find the greatest common divisor of $q^{2^a}+1$  and $q^{2^b}+1$.

Comment: Is this a research type question? Could you specify the source please? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530573/are-there-infinitely-many-natural-numbers-n-such-that-mun-mun1-pm-1/) is a very similar question ...

Comment: It is an Olympiad question.